# PHP not running after upgrade

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I'm having some trouble getting PHP to run under Apache after updating my software. On my Amazon AWS running AMI, I followed [this guide here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=465912), with the specific commands:

- sudo yum remove httpd* php*
- sudo yum install httpd24 php55

After updating the apache config files to use the newer directives, I can get to the server, but the PHP is just echoing out on the screen.

I checked to make sure that there is a php.ini file being read, that the module is loaded in Apache, the server is running, and I can execute php from the command line.

Anyone have any ideas on what I should check next?

Comment: You restarted the services?

Comment: Yup, multiple times and it's up and running, that's what's so odd... I've done a bunch of googling, tried a few things, even threw in the php_flag engine 1 rule into my config and nothing.